# NullPointerException when referencing a property of a JTabbedPane

Tags: java

What is wrong with the logic behind creating a `JTabbedPane` and getting the tab count
of 11, then using a setter?

I try to reference the `tabCount` of the `SetObjects.currentJTabbedPane` and it throws
`NullPointerException`.

**create**

```
jtp.setSelectedIndex(0);

int jtpCount=jtp.getTabCount();
System.out.println(C+M+AND+jtpCount+": jtpCount of The JTabbedPane created: \n");

setCurrentJTabbedPane(jtp);
int currentCount=SetObjects.currentJTabbedPane.getTabCount();
System.out.println(C+M+AND+currentCount+": currentCount for
    SetObjects.currentJTabbedPane.getTabCount() : \n");
```

**setter**

```
public static void setCurrentJTabbedPane(JTabbedPane currentJTabbedPane) {
    String M =(" --> in setCurrentJTabbedPane() var: <-- \n");
    System.out.println(M);

    SetObjects.currentJTabbedPane = currentJTabbedPane;
    System.out.println(C+M+AND+SetObjects.currentJTabbedPane.getTabCount()+":
        SetObjects.currentJTabbedPane.getTabCount() : \n");
}
```

**output**

> CLASS
>   SetObjects:
>   --> JTabbedPane obj() var: xxxxxxxxx : xxxxxxxx<--
>       : 11: jtpCount of The JTabbedPane created:
>
> ```
> --> in setCurrentJTabbedPane() var: <--
> ```
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>    at view.SetObjects.setCurrentJTabbedPane(SetObjects.java:385)
>    at view.SetObjects.obj(SetObjects.java:217)
>    at view.SchoolJDesktopPane.createInnerFrame(SchoolJDesktopPane.java:119)
>    at view.SchoolJDesktopPane.(SchoolJDesktopPane.java:97)
>    at view.Main.createJDesktopPane(Main.java:60)
>    at view.Main.main(Main.java:54)

Comment: Where do you initialize `currentJTabbedPane` in **create**?

Comment: I see you have updated your post and you are now passing `jtp` to setCurrentJTabbedPane. Have you just fixed your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Are you passing `null` to `setCurrentJTabbedPane`? Try adding more System.out.println statements to inspect each variable that might be the problem. Also, make your debugging statements simpler, i.e. replace `System.out.println(A + B + C)` with three different statements.

EDIT: The reason for splitting up debug statements is that if `System.out.println(object1.foo() + ", " + object2.bar())` throws a NullPointerException then you don't know which object was null. Splitting it into two statements means the stack trace tells you exactly where the problem was.

Comment: sorry jtp is the created JTabbedPane.